# Why does extracting a single column of a matrix in R produces... object of NULL dimension?

Tags: r, matrix

I have generated this 3*3 matrix in R:

```
           [,1]        [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  0.2145235  0.00541706 -1.671136
[2,]  0.8661748  1.03257839 -1.447193
[3,] -0.4474127 -0.21663935  1.310579
```

Let us assume I take the two last columns: `group_of_cols=P[,1:2]`, I have

```
dim(group_of_cols)

[1] 3 2
```

that's perfect. Now let us assume, I am just taking the second column: `my_col=P[,2]`, I have

```
dim(my_col)

NULL
```

I am usual Matlab user and this is really, really mindfucking to observe this. Why the hell isn't a single column of a matrix of size 3*1 but "NULL" ??

And the question in itself: how to get the expected dimension 3*1 of one column of the matrix ?
Also, if someone can explain me the logical behind the why R is behaving like this, I would be more than happy

Answer (score 3):

`[` by default returns the lowest possible dimension. Which in this case is a vector since you are subsetting from a matrix.

To return a 3x1 matrix you need to add `drop=FALSE`

```
P <- matrix(rnorm(9), ncol = 3)
set.seed(1234)
P <- matrix(rnorm(9), ncol = 3)
P[,2, drop=F]

#           [,1]
#[1,] -2.3456977
#[2,]  0.4291247
#[3,]  0.5060559
```

As to the logic of this behavior, I have no idea...